# OAuth2 service and Symfony web framework communication

Tags: symfony, go, oauth-2.0

There is a Symfony application and there is our Authentication service which provides login for our third-party clients. The problem: If someone login through the Symfony app the Authservice can't get it, and if someone login with Symfony app (FOS User Bundle) the Authservice can't get it.

These are under one domain www.domain.com for Symfony and auth.domain.com for authservice, so somehow they can read each other's session. I know in PHP this is the session.cookie_domain option, but the Authservice is written in Go and I don't know how to solve it in two different language.

Comment: Having trouble seeing where oauth2 fits in.  Typically, a Symfony app would redirect the user to facebook/google which in turn authenticates the user and redirects back to the Symfony app.  The Symfony app would then login the authenticated user.  I really don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @Cerad I refresh it based on my new knowledge.